# How to display "head" of web pages without scrolling iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Many times I am only interested in the first portion 
and would like to make a "collage", say of arriving buses at nearby stops and fit more on a small screen.
I found I can use "iframe", but having the cursor in the frame of course scrolls the frame 
rather than scroll me further down the web page.  Just for variety I include an image too.

Is there a better way to post "heads" of web pages? (I probably know to little about CSS and Bootstrap, etc.)

Running the snippet here shows only the traffic cam, but pasting it for example into  http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ or local html file runs just fine.  https://codepen.io/pen/ shows pugetsound "refuses to connect".

```html
<div class="thumbnail-container">

   <iframe height="260px" width="322px" src="http://pugetsound.onebusaway.org/where/iphone/stop.action?id=1_14961" frameborder="0"></iframe>

   <iframe height="260px" width="322px" src="http://pugetsound.onebusaway.org/where/iphone/stop.action?id=1_15540" frameborder="0"></iframe>

   <img src="http://www.seattle.gov/trafficcams/images/WSB_Midspan_EW.jpg" width="400" />   <!-- or a placekitten.com ;-)  -->

   <iframe height="260px" width="322px" src="http://pugetsound.onebusaway.org/where/iphone/stop.action?id=1_19930" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</div>
```

[image]

Just to show that there are other example applications I run into frequently 
would be the weather for the next 2 days only, or the temperature for the last few days.
An answer to above would solve many problems.

height=380px  http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.578&lon=-122.403&FcstType=text&TextType=2

height 120px  https://atmos.washington.edu/~neal/uwp/index72.cgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is you do not want the iFrame to scroll, you can try:

```
<iframe src="" scrolling="no"></iframe>

iframe { overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: Yes, the scrolling="no" solved exactly what I was looking for and did not know.  Thanks!  The overflow presumably would be used with a style.